# Structuring and publishing a Vue component to NPM

Tags: vue.js, npm, module, publish

I'm trying to publish my Vue component(s) to NPM but I'm running into some issues.

I followed these instructions: https://www.xiegerts.com/post/creating-vue-component-library-structure/

My structure is as follows:

[image]

The package is published here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-vue-formgenerator

Now, when I install my package using NPM and try to use it, it cannot find it. Webstorm also underlines the name of the package telling me the module has not been installed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you specified `"main"` property in your `package.json`?

Comment: @Javas That was indeed part of the problem! Thank you! I got it to work.